# Child operation with select() does not stop running after execvp()

Tags: c, select, fork

Running this snippet of code to experiment with piping and signals. I'm trying to learn how to properly utilize the select() function between pipes.

This process will fork. If there is something to be read from stdIn it is then written to the write end of the pipe. It is supposed to execute either a basic command entered via terminal, or it runs hard-coded commands in the code. (It's running hard code right now as "ls.")

When I run this snippet, it should quit and stop running completely when I press the letter "q" followed by ENTER, or it should quit after it runs its assigned process.

Instead, even after I hit "q" or run the process it won't stop the program completely. It is still waiting for input. It *will* stop running once I have hit ENTER, but it never even executes my process.

For example, if I compile and run this as "./test ls" or even just run "./test" (because ls is hard-coded in so that SHOULD just run I think), it will not run the command ls. And the program will continue to run until I've hit ENTER again.

I'm certain my rudimentary understanding of select() has to do with this issue. I'm pretty sure my select() statement needs to break at some point but I don't know what or how to check for this.

I was told that there is a method WIFEXITED() that might be able to help me but I'm just not sure how it applies in this context.

I also would like to know how to check if your pipes are empty!

I DO know that I want this to be able to both take input from the terminal and record it and also run built in functions.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int in[2]; // parent writes; child reads
  pipe(in);
  if (fork() == 0) {
    // instantiate the values that will be execed
    char *a[2];
    //a[0] = "./test3";
    a[0] = "ls";
    a[1] = NULL;

    // redirects what is being read from stdin to the pipe
    //this redirection is for a separate test that is not included
    close(in[1]);
    close(0);
    dup(in[0]);

    close(in[0]); // close read
    execvp(a[0], a);
  }
  else {
    close(in[0]); // only want parent to write

    // select() params
    int nfds = 3;
    int check = -1;
    int done = 0;
    fd_set readfds;
    fd_set writefds;

    FD_ZERO(&readfds); // set select params
    FD_SET(0, &readfds);
    FD_SET(in[1], &writefds);

    while ((check = select(nfds, &readfds, &writefds, NULL, NULL)) > 0) {
      int size = 0;
      char buf[1000];

      // write to pipe for child
      if (FD_ISSET(0, &readfds) && FD_ISSET(in[1], &writefds)) {
        while ((size = read(0, buf, sizeof(buf))) != 0) {

          write(in[1], buf, size);
        }
      }
      // reset
      FD_ZERO(&readfds);
      FD_SET(0, &readfds);
      FD_SET(in[1], &writefds);
    }
    printf("%d --------------- %d\n", (FD_ISSET(in[1], &writefds)),
           FD_ISSET(0, &readfds));
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Here is the potential set of test code that can be run with the above snipped if a[0] = ./test is uncommented and a[0] = ls is commented.

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/select.h>

int main () {

    int fd;
    char buf[11];
    int ret, sret;
    int flag = 0;
    fd = 0;

    fd_set readfds;
    struct timeval timeout;


    while(1) {

        FD_ZERO(&readfds);
        FD_SET(fd, &readfds);

        timeout.tv_sec = 5;
        timeout.tv_usec = 0;

        sret = select(fd + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);

            memset((void *) buf, 0, 11);
            ret = read(fd, (void *) buf, 10);
            flag = strcmp(buf, "q\n") == 0;

            if (flag) {
                return 0;
            }
            printf("ret = %d\n", ret);

            if(ret != -1) {
                printf(" buf = %s\n", buf);
            }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `&& (in[1], &writefds)` ????

Comment: so sorry. that was a typo. that wants to be "FD_ISSET(in[1], &writefds)"

Comment: select's first argument (nfds) is defined as "nfds is the highest-numbered file descriptor in any of the three sets, plus 1."... you have it hardcoded as 3, which is probably incorrect... it should be "in[1] + 1".

Comment: you inverse your pipe. in[0] is the out, in[1] is the in. Replace 0 for ls is useless, ls don't read standard input.

Comment: @TonyB thanks for the input! I will change this in the example provided. I had it this this way as a test when I was originally working only with standard input. I forgot to change this as my potential number of file descriptors increased.@Stargateur there was a different program I was using that DID require input, which is whyI was redirecting standard in. I deleted connections to this program as a way of making what I posted her online more simple, but in my haste I fogot to change some minor details relating this code to that other test snippet.

Comment: I included the test case re-direct

Comment: You have a comment in your redirect test case about select() "timing out"... select() will wait indefinitely if the "timeout" argument is NULL, as it is in your test-case .

Comment: If however you change it to this, then timeout will work:  "sret = select(fd + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);"

Comment: i purposefully do NULL so it waits indefinitely for input. This is in the case of manual input. I know that the timeout will never happen. That is from when I HAD a timeout but got rid of it.

Comment: You didn't fix the problem of nfds plus select only guarantee one call to read that don't block if you loop until read select is useless. Remove your while loop with read. By the way, `read(0, &buf, sizeof(buf)` => `read(0, buf, sizeof(buf)` and `write(in[1], &buf, size)` => `write(in[1], buf, size)`

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to properly use WIFEXITED() or some method in this context so it closes the select after it registers and runs input.

Comment: @Stargateur thanks! this is actually ueseful =) I'll get to working on that.